# How to load a content page(xaml) to another page(xaml) in xamarin.Forms , but keep the header and footer same (like tab in Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I wish to create a custom tabbed page in Xamarin.Forms where both the Header and Footer remain the same. With the center section containing the content.

The Header is generally a text heading. Only the centre portion of the screen keeps changing according to tab selection.

The Footer contain the different tabs. It's also not like a usual tabbed page. It's more like a Button that changes color when selected and that has a definite gap between them.

**Here's an example image**

[image: Expected]

Comment: You can use content view inside the content page.

Comment: @PragneshMistry View in xmarin.Forms ?

Comment: Yes ContentView, I have used content view inside the content page

Answer (score 1):

You can create ContentViews by right-clicking the project, pressing 'add' and then add a ContentView.

You can then use a grid and create different rows and reference the ContentViews on one row and the header and footer on two other rows.

Reference the ContentViews like this in the top of the `Xaml`.

```
xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:SharedTestProject.ContentViews"
```

Then define the rest of the `Xaml` like this. All you have to do after that is to implement the logic to change which view is visible.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="NavigationButtons" HeightRequest="55" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="140" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Button x:Name="BtnView1" Clicked="BtnView1_Clicked" Text="View1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="140" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Button x:Name="BtnView2" Clicked="BtnView2_Clicked" Text="View2"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="140" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Button x:Name="BtnView3" Clicked="BtnView3_Clicked" Text="View3"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentViews" Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentViews:View1 x:Name="View1" IsVisible="True"/>
        <ContentViews:View2 x:Name="View2" IsVisible="False"/>
        <ContentViews:View3 x:Name="View3" IsVisible="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: will this work with loading data like what we usually do OnAppearing? What about animation?